# Algorithm to compute the Teichmuller character

Tags: number-theory, p-adic-number-theory

For a given prime number $p$ (for simplicity, let's assume $p\neq 2$), the Teichmuller character is a character of the multiplicative group $(\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z})^{\times}$ that takes values in the roots of unity of $p$-adic integers. Does anyone know an efficient algorithm to compute the Teichmuller representatives of $\{1,2,\cdots,p-1 \}$ to some order?

More precisely, given an element $a \in \{1,2,\cdots,p-1 \}$, and an integer $n$, compute the Teichmuller representative up to order $p^n$!

Comment: Well $\tau(a) = a^{p^{n-1}}$ mod $p^n$, cf. https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2737861/96384. So you want an efficient algorithm to compute the integer $a^{p^{k}}$, or its residue mod $p^{k+1}$? Then https://math.stackexchange.com/q/21601/96384 seems related.

Comment: I don't know whether this is helpful, but I once fiddled out a procedure to compute a certain set of coefficients and found out later that this was exactly the focus of the Teichmuller-character. Maybe you want to look into http://go.helms-net.de/math/expdioph/fermatquotients.pdf perhaps that computation there is "efficient" enough in your sense?

Comment: @TorstenSchoeneberg I want to compute the residue mod $p^{k+1}$. The problem with $a^{p^k}$ is that it grows too fast. I also tried the method using Hensel lemma, which is also not very efficient.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It’s an easy algorithm, but fairly slowly convergent one, to start with $\beta\in(\Bbb Z/p\Bbb Z)^\times$, lift to *any* $b\in\Bbb Z$ that reduces to $\beta$, and successively raise to the $p$-th power. That is, go $b\mapsto b^p\mapsto(b^p)^p=b^{p^2}\mapsto b^{p^3}\mapsto\cdots$. You get one more place of $p$-adic accuracy each time you do it.

Why does it work? Because if $b\equiv b'\pmod{p^m}$, then $b^p\equiv{b'}^p\pmod{p^{m+1}}$, easily shown, though you should be careful if $p=2$ and $m$ is small.